# How to manually generate network parameters in Corda

Tags: x509certificate, corda

I have manually created and distributed the required certificates for Corda nodes. Now for the nodes to start, among other things, they need to have a network parameter. The problem is that if I use the Corda network bootstrapper tool to generate the network parameter, the file will be signed by another issuer ("C=UK, L=London, OU=corda, O=R3, CN=Corda Node Root CA") which is different from the issuer of my certificates. My question is how can I manually create a network parameter so I can specify the correct issuer to avoid conflicts during node startup?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I have figured a way to create network parameters:

```
private fun getSignedNetworkParameters(): NetworkParameters {

        //load the notary from a Keystore. This avoids having to start a flow from a node in order to retrieve NotaryInfo
        val notary = loadKeyStore("\\path-to-keystore\\keystore.jks", "keystore-password")

        val certificateAndKeyPair : CertificateAndKeyPair = notary.getCertificateAndKeyPair("entry-alias", "entry-password")
        val notaryParty = Party(certificateAndKeyPair.certificate)
        val notaryInfo = listOf(NotaryInfo(notaryParty, false))

        //map contract ID to the SHA-256 hash of its CorDapp contracts&states JAR file
        val whitelistedContractImplementations = mapOf(
                TestContract.TEST_CONTRACT_ID to listOf(getCheckSum(contractFile))
        )

        return NetworkParameters(minimumPlatformVersion = 3, notaries = notaryInfo,
                maxMessageSize = n, maxTransactionSize = n, modifiedTime = Instant.now(),
                epoch = 1, whitelistedContractImplementations = whitelistedContractImplementations)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could sign your certificates with the development certificate that is used by the network bootstrapper: https://github.com/corda/corda/tree/master/node-api/src/main/resources/certificates

If that doesn't work for you, you could try this experimental tool: https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/experimental/netparams/src/main/kotlin/net.corda.netparams/NetParams.kt . I can't promise that it works with Corda 3.3 though.

Comment: Both links are 404 now